# text inside bootstrap div is not respecting div bounds using angular 8

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 boarder">
      fjkdfjklsddfsfdkjdfskjldfskljdfdsfjkldfsdfsf
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      whatever
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css file

```
.boarder{
  border: solid 1px blueviolet;
}
```

there is the html code

Here is proof the bootstrap was installed correctly:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
              ],
```

Here is what the damn thing looks like

[image: what the thing looks like]

why for this? You know why for this? Please explain why for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;` it will break the long words. [Note](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)